# GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS_EXT substitude?

Tags: opengl

I have an old OGL code that I'm trying to compile on my Mac OSX 10.6, however when I compile and run, it says that  GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS_EXT is not supported. What can I use to replace it so that it will run? The OGL version on my Mac is 2.1, and this EXT was supported since 1.4 or so, so I thought that it run correctly but apparently not. What can I replace it with?

Comment: I meant 2.1. I used glGetString(GL_VERSION)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace it by getting rid of the `_EXT` suffix. It's a *core feature* to OpenGL 2.1. You shouldn't be checking for the extension at all; the version says 2.1, so `GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS` is available.